# Centos 8 apache kerberos authentication sso

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, http, kerberos

For some reason I am unable to authenticate via sso to internal website when you connect it directly via cname. Centos linux is joined in the domain itself.

What happens is that when I enter the website first time it will display a pop-up asking to authenticate via AD lookup. When I authenticate successfully I am logged into the website. When I log out and click sign in again it will auto login without asking for username and password. This kind of looks to me that browser has stored the data already and when making a new request towards internal website it can already pass the data.

However, whenever I initiate a new session (incognito) it will ask again the username and password.
Apache does not display any errors.

On my IIS webserver this works with the same software and auto login. Looks more to be something with my kerberos and apacahe configuration.

I am using kerberos + apache for sso.

Configuration file for krb5.conf looks like this

```
[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    forwardable = true
    rdns = false
    pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    default_realm = example.com
    default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
    example.com = {
     kdc = example.com
     admin_server = example.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Apache virtualhost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/requests.log combined    

<Directory /var/www/example.com/html/tickets>
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Kerberos Authntication"
    KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.COM
    Krb5Keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
    KrbMethodNegotiate Off
    KrbSaveCredentials Off
    KrbVerifyKDC Off
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


[o@38900000li003 ~]$ hostname -f
38900000LI003.example.com
```

If I use the following configuration in VirtualHost I will get this error message in apache error log

```
 <Directory /var/www/example.com/html/tickets>

AuthType Kerberos
KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.COM
KrbServiceName HTTP
Krb5Keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
KrbMethodNegotiate on
KrbMethodK5Passwd on
require valid-user
```

```
gss_acquire_cred() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (, No key table entry found matching HTTP/38900000li003.example.com@)
```

I am looking at the Keytab I can see info is provided there.

```
[o@38900000li003 ~]$ cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/krb5.keytab
HTTP/example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Edit:
I can see that Kerberos can access AD without problems by using this command as it does not throw any errors

```
[o@38900000li003 ~]$ kinit -p administrator@EXAMPLE.COM -V
Using existing cache: 1000
Using principal: administrator@EXAMPLE.COM
Password for administrator@EXAMPLE.COM:
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
```

Keytab

```
sudo klist -k
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 38900000LI003$@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 38900000LI003$@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 host/38900000LI003@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 host/38900000LI003@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 host/38900000li003.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 host/38900000li003.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 RestrictedKrbHost/38900000LI003@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 RestrictedKrbHost/38900000LI003@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 RestrictedKrbHost/38900000li003.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 RestrictedKrbHost/38900000li003.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Edit2: Some logs when I set up error logging to debug in apache.
https://pastebin.com/N0hzQPcs

Edit3: Could it be that auto sso does not work because we are not using legacy logon for loging into windows machine. e.g instead of example as username we are using email e.g username@example.com ?

```
[o@38900000li003 ~]$ tail -20 /var/www/example.comm/log/error.log  | grep example.com
[Tue Oct 06 16:45:24.421009 2020] [auth_kerb:error] [pid 107473:tid 139631928502016] [client 10.126.1.25:2962] Specified realm `example.com' not allowed by configuration
[Tue Oct 06 16:45:29.285545 2020] [auth_kerb:error] [pid 107473:tid 139631894931200] [client 10.126.1.25:2962] Specified realm `example.com' not allowed by configuration
[Tue Oct 06 16:47:23.531914 2020] [auth_kerb:error] [pid 107687:tid 139631769138944] [client 10.126.1.25:2975] Specified realm `example.com' not allowed by configuration
```